# why pyinstaller coudn't get the width and height of the screen correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller to generate the executive version of my scripts and it did it well. it run on my computer well but when I run it in my friend's laptop the bottom part of program doesn't show. I don't know why. anyone has any clue? I guess that it cannot get the width of the screen correctly.

I also tried pywin32, GetSystemMetrics for getting the width of my screen but unfortunately it is not supported by pyinstaller.

```
root = tk.Tk()

root.title("software")

window_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()

window_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
```

I guess that this part of the code is not adjustable to any system. (windows)

Comment: What are you actually *doing* with the window size values?  The code you posted doesn't actually exhibit anything.

Comment: @jasonharper I pass the window size to tinter root to create the window and put the widgets on it. but in some systems. when I run my .exe file it's not able to show the widgets which are in the bottom of the screen they are cuted somehow. specially when the screen of the monitors are small.

Comment: If you are forcing the window to a particular size, and that size is not enough to hold all of the widgets in the window, then *of course* they're going to be cut off - what other outcome can you possibly imagine?  You may need an alternate layout to be used on smaller monitors, or make some or all of the window contents scrollable.